# GKE auto-pilot and node-pools

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Still not that familiar with Kubernetes and GKE, so I was curious whether some of you might know more about this.
I have a GKE cluster with auto-pilot enabled. This seems to work great.

I don’t have any real traffic yet, everything is in development. I therefore do not expect auto-scaling to scale up to more than 1 node at the moment. I have a few workloads/services and they request 2.25vCPU and 3.75 memory in total (so not much).

As I want to keep costs low during development, I was wondering why it looks like 5 nodes have been created?
`kubectl get nodes` shows 5 different nodes, 4 in the ‘default pool’, 1 in a pool with a seemingly-random name.

Does anybody know:

1. Why 2 node-pools have been created? Is this something the auto-pilot does? Are both node-pools required?
2. Why there are 5 nodes in total? Is this the minimum and would resizing it to 1 (in total, so removing a node-pool and resizing) work? Or are all 5 nodes required?
3. It is not allowed to resize node-pools when using auto-pilot: 
    `ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Autopilot clusters do not support mutating node pools.`

    Is there any way to force auto-pilot to only scale to a maximum of 1 node?

If I missed documentation online, sorry for that. I have been looking around, but most of the documentation around auto-pilot still feels a little vague compared to the ‘standard’-version. I do prefer to keep using auto-pilot to reduce developer time.

Comment: AFAIK, with GKE Autopilot you will only be charged for resources that are requested by your pods. The number of nodes running those pods is an implementation detail that you should not need to worry about.

Comment: That is correct - in Autopilot mode, node pools are out of your control and you only pay for resources used by your pods. For reference: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GKE Autopilot, you don't need to worry about nodes or nodepools at all.  Autopilot will spin nodes up and down based on the resources needed by your deployments, but you will only be charged for the resources requested by your actual deployments.  If you don't specify resource requests in your deployment spec, then Autopilot will set CPU to 500m and Memory to 2gb.  If your app requires less resources than that, make sure you set the resource request for your deployment.  The minimum CPU is 250m and the minimum memory is 512mb.

Comment: minimum CPU is now 500m

Comment: Minimum CPU is now 250m